# iOS - UIView container hidden behind keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am working on a storyboard view with a form the user fills out.  Down at the bottom is a UIView footer containing a checkbox and submit button.  When the user enters data into the text fields, the keyboard displays and hides the footer - only when hiding the keyboard will the user be able to check the checkbox and submit the form.  I have seen some solutions for moving text fields in from behind a keyboard, but not for a UIView.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how this can be done?

[image: no keyboard]

[image: hidden once keyboard is in view]

Comment: Either you can close the keyboard ny hitting the return key or you can move the view with an offset or you can display a temp footer view on top of keyboard .Please show what you have tried!

Comment: The best way to handle keyboard is through IQKeyboardManager library. Try it here. https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: @SivajeeBattina That only handles the case where textfields are covered by keyboard. But not if other views that are covered by keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I just wanted to follow up with the method I used to fix my issue. The footer container has a vertical spacing constraint with the Bottom Layout Guide.  I created an IBOutlet for the constraint...

```
//define IBOutlet
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *footerConstraint;
```

I then added code to adjust the constant value to the keyboard management event handlers...

```
//in keyboardWillShow event handler
NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
self.footerConstraint.constant = kbSize.height;


//in keyboardWillHide event handler
self.footerConstraint.constant = 0.0f;
```

By adjusting the constraint's constant value in these event handlers, I can keep the default value until the keyboard is displayed, then set the default value back after the keyboard is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

The standard solution is described in [“Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard” in the *Text Programming Guide for iOS*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7):

> Adjusting your content typically involves temporarily resizing one or more views and positioning them so that the text object remains visible. The simplest way to manage text objects with the keyboard is to embed them inside a `UIScrollView` object (or one of its subclasses like `UITableView`). When the keyboard is displayed, all you have to do is reset the content area of the scroll view and scroll the desired text object into position. Thus, in response to a `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`, your handler method would do the following:
>
> 1. Get the size of the keyboard.
> 2. Adjust the bottom content inset of your scroll view by the keyboard height.
> 3. Scroll the target text field into view.

Step 2 makes it possible for the user to scroll the scroll view up far enough to see everything in it, including (in your case) the terms of use checkbox and the submit button.

**However,** there is a way to get UIKit to do all of that for you: lay out your form in your storyboard as a table view with static cells. I recommend you do it this way instead.

When you lay out your form as a table view with static cells, you can still connect the form controls (text fields, buttons, etc.) to outlets and actions in your view controller (which must now be a subclass of `UITableViewController`). The `UITableViewController` base class takes care of setting the table view's `contentInset` when the keyboard appears and disappears, and takes care of scrolling the table view to ensure the current text field is visible.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  The form itself is inside a ScrollView, whereas the footer is in a UIView underneath the ScrollView.  Would moving the footer into the ScrollView rather than underneath it help?  Or should I just look to put the form and footer into a TableView?  This is something that another developer built and there are a number constraints in place - I would like to avoid massively restructuring things if at all possible.

Comment: It sounds like you should just move the footer into the scroll view.